# to improve cache hit rate, How can I revise the program

Tags: c

> Change the program to improve the cache hit rate and write the revised program. In addition, for the same cache (8word block size) in (a), compute the data cache miss rate.

This is my assignment.

How could I revise this code?

```
int a[1024], b[1024], c[1024], d[1024];

void main(){ 
   int s=0;
   for(int i=0; i<1024; ++i){
     s += a[i]*b[i]+c[i]*d[i];
   }
}
```

Assume that the starting addresses of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are `0x0000`, `0x1000`, `0x2000`, and `0x3000`, respectively.
so the miss rate of this cod is 100% because of the starting address.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Wait, so what do you think happens _after_ the first four accesses all miss?

Answer (score 4):

A basic improvement would be to use an array of struct:

```
struct ABCD
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
}
ABCD v[1024];

void main()
{
    int s=0; 
    for(int i=0; i<1024; ++i) 
    {
        s += v[i].a*v[i].b+v[i].c*v[i].d;
    }
}
```

This way, you'd page in each location just once. All memory accesses would be done near recently accessed data.

If changing the data format is not an option, maybe the intented solution is to loop over the data twice, once for each side of the `+` operator. Then the solution would look like:

```
void main()
{
    int s=0; 
    for(int i=0; i<1024; ++i) 
    {
        s += a[i]*b[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<1024; ++i) 
    {
        s += c[i]*d[i];
    }
}
```

(I just notice the C tag, as opposed to C++. So, there might be a missing fix around the struct declaration)